# Can I include canonical URLs in sitemap for SEO?

Tags: url, seo, duplicates, sitemap, canonical-link

Can I include canonical URLs in sitemaps for SEO?

For example `www.example.com/url.html` is a duplicate page of `www.example2.com/url.html`.

So I used following tag in `www.example.com/url.html` page for SEO not to be penalized by search engines:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.example2.com/url.html">
```

Now my question is can I display `www.example.com/url.html` URL inside of `www.example.com/sitemap.xml`?

I already display `www.example2.com/url.html` URL inside of `www.example2.com/sitemap.xml`.

Please suggest me what I have to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include these two pages into your *sitemap.xml* and there won't be a problem for SEO because you're using the `rel="canonical"` tag. Indeed, when web crawlers will try to index the duplicate page, they will see the `rel="canonical"` tag and they will index the second page (the good one).

Answer (score 1):

For better index you must leave one URL - canonical URL in XML site map

Comment: You should elaborate on your answer some. What does that XML site map look like? Why should there be only one canonical?